# re-arrange and combine powershell custom objects

Tags: powershell, object, hashtable

I have a system that currently reads data from a CSV file produced by a separate system that is going to be replaced.

The imported CSV file looks like this

```
PS> Import-Csv .\SalesValues.csv
Sale Values AA BB
----------- -- --
10          6  5
5           3  4
3           1  9
```

To replace this process I hope to produce an object that looks identical to the CSV above, but I do not want to continue to use a CSV file.

I already have a script that reads data in from our database and extracts the data that I need to use. I'll not detail the fairly long script that preceeds this point but in effect it looks like this:

```
$SQLData = Custom-SQLFunction "SELECT * FROM SALES_DATA WHERE LIST_ID = $LISTID"
```

`$SQLData` will contain ~5000+ DataRow objects that I need to query.

One of those DataRow object looks something like this:

```
lead_id                 : 123456789
entry_date              : 26/10/2018 16:51:16
modify_date             : 01/11/2018 01:00:02
status                  : WRONG
user                    : mrexample
vendor_lead_code        : TH1S15L0NGC0D3
source_id               : A543212
list_id                 : 333004
list_name               : AA Some Text
gmt_offset_now          : 0.00
SaleValue               : 10
```

`list_name` is going to be prefixed with `AA` or `BB`.

`SaleValue` can be any integer 3 and up, however realistically extremely unlikely to be higher than 100 (as this is a monthly donation) and will be one of 3,5,10 in the vast majority of occurrences.

I already have script that takes the content of list_name, creates and populates the data I need to use into two separate psobjects (`$AASalesValues` and `$BBSalesValues`) that collates the total numbers of 'SaleValue' across the data set.

Because I cannot reliably anticipate the value of any SaleValue I have to dynamically create the psobjects properties like this

```
foreach ($record in $SQLData) {
    if ($record.list_name -match "BB") {
        if ($record.SaleValue -gt 0) {
            if ($BBSalesValues | Get-Member -Name $($record.SaleValue) -MemberType Properties) {
                $BBSalesValues.$($record.SaleValue) = $BBSalesValues.$($record.SaleValue)+1
            } else {
                $BBSalesValues | Add-Member -Name $($record.SaleValue) -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 1
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

The two resultant objects look like this:

```
PS> $AASalesValues
10  5 3 50
--  - - --
17 14 3  1

PS> $BBSalesvalues
 3 10  5 4
 - --  - -
36 12 11 1
```

I now have the data that I need, however I need to format it in a way that *replicates* the format of the CSV so I can pass it directly to another existing powershell script that is configured to expect the data in the format that the CSV is in, but I do not want to write the data to a file.

I'd prefer to pass this directly to the next part of the script.

Ultimately what I want to do is to produce a new object/some output that looks like the output from `Import-Csv` command at the top of this post.

I'd like a new object, say `$OverallSalesValues`, to look like this:

```
PS>$overallSalesValues
Sale Values  AA  BB
50           1   0
10           17  12
5            14  11
4            0   1
3            3   36
```

In the above example the values from `$AASalesValues` is listed under the AA column, the values from `$BBSalesValues` is listed under the BB column, with the rows matching the headers of the two original objects.

I did try this with hashtables but I was unable to work out how to both create them from dynamic values and format them to how I needed them to look.

Comment: Are Sale Values unique?

Comment: Does the CSV contain the leading `£` in the `Sale Values` column? Also, where does `$record` come from, and why are you bulding custom objects from it instead of hashtables?

Comment: Woulnd't grouping on `$record.SaleValue` be better choice ?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Hastables Record a Key and Value, I need multiple columns (key, Value1, Value2) like in the final example. I don't understand how to construct that data in that way. Thats pretty much what I'm asking for help with.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 SalesValues is going to be an integer between of 3 or greater. Most commonly it's going to be 3,5 or 10 but there will be outliers (eg 4 or 50 in my final example) and I can't anticipate what they will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got there.

```
$TotalList = @()
foreach($n in 3..200){
    if($AASalesValues.$n -or $BBSalesValues.$n){
        $AACount = $AASalesValues.$n
        $BBcount = $BBSalesValues.$n

        $values = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Sale Value'= $n
            AA = $AACount
            BB = $BBcount
            }
        $TotalList += $values
        }
    }
$TotalList
```

produces an output of

```
Sale Value AA BB
---------- -- --
         3  3 36
         4     2
         5 14 11
        10 18 12
        50  1
```

Just need to add a bit to include '0' values instead of $null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `$record` contains a list of the database results for either `$AASalesValues` or `$BBSalesValues`, not both, otherwise you'd need some kind of selector to avoid counting records of one group with the other group.

Group the records by their `SaleValue` property as [LotPings suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177454/re-arrange-and-combine-powershell-custom-objects/53192126#comment93245590_53177454):

```
$BBSalesValues = $record | Group-Object SaleValue -NoElement
```

That will give you a list of the `SaleValue` values with their respective count.

```
PS> $BBSalesValues
Count Name
----- ----
   36 3
   12 10
   11 5
    1 4
```

You can then update your CSV data with these values like this:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\data.csv'

# read CSV into a hashtable mapping the sale value to the complete record
# (so that we can lookup the record by sale value)
$csv = @{}
Import-Csv $file | ForEach-Object {
    $csv[$_.'Sale Values'] = $_
}

# Add records for missing sale values
$($AASalesValues; $BBSalesValues) | Select-Object -Expand Name -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not $csv.ContainsKey($_)) {
        $csv[$_] = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'Sale Values' = $_
            'AA'          = 0
            'BB'          = 0
        }
    }
}

# update records with values from $AASalesValues
$AASalesValues | ForEach-Object {
    [int]$csv[$_.Name].AA += $_.Count
}

# update records with values from $BBSalesValues
$BBSalesValues | ForEach-Object {
    [int]$csv[$_.Name].BB += $_.Count
}

# write updated records back to file
$csv.Values | Export-Csv $file -NoType
```

---

Even with your updated question the approach would be pretty much the same, you'd just add another level of grouping for collecting the sales numbers:

```
$sales = @{}
$record | Group-Object {$_.list_name.Split()[0]} | ForEach-Object {
    $sales[$_.Name] = $_.Group | Group-Object SaleValue -NoElement
}
```

and then adjust the merging to something like this:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\data.csv'

# read CSV into a hashtable mapping the sale value to the complete record
# (so that we can lookup the record by sale value)
$csv = @{}
Import-Csv $file | ForEach-Object {
    $csv[$_.'Sale Values'] = $_
}

# Add records for missing sale values
$sales.Values | Select-Object -Expand Name -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not $csv.ContainsKey($_)) {
        $prop = @{'Sale Values' = $_}
        $sales.Keys | ForEach-Object {
            $prop[$_] = 0
        }
        $csv[$_] = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $prop
    }
}

# update records with values from $sales
$sales.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Key
    $_.Value | ForEach-Object {
        [int]$csv[$_.Name].$name += $_.Count
    }
}

# write updated records back to file
$csv.Values | Export-Csv $file -NoType
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for spending the time looking at this, I'm afraid the terrible way I worded my question means that your answer isn't what I was looking for. I eventually worked it out myself anyway and have posted an answer. I've re-written the question to hopefully be clearer to anyone who finds it in the future. Ultimately my question was an extremely long winded way of saying 'how do i do a custom hashtable based on these objects' I assumed that the extra detail would help but in the end it just confused matters.

Comment: @Patrick Even with your updated question the approach remains roughly the same. See updated answer.